# Object Variable coming up undefined in onsubmit function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, express

The redirect function gets called on submit of a form and for some reason the data object is not getting carried into the function and begin passed on the ajax post request. By the time the data object is called, it has 6 properties. The post route to express works and is successful but I am having trouble getting the data object to be sent.

any help is appreciated, thank you.

This portion is the express code and the part below is the app.js

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' });
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));



app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.post('/Summary',jsonParser, function (req, res) {
    console.log("post"+ req.body + ' h');
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

////////  App.js code   /////

```
 var data = {roommate:1};


function redirect(){

    var data=JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(data +' f');
$.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: data,
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        url: 'http://localhost:3000/Summary',                       
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log('success');
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(data + 'h'));
                        }
                    });

};
```

Comment: Did you try sending `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of JSON strings to the server

Comment: I didnt do a form because I had to append each value to an object before submittal

Comment: jQuery accepts objects, and will convert them to `x-www-form-urlencoded` by default, which is probably what your bodyParser expects as well, the only things you have to do is not stringify the object, and not set the contentType header

Comment: I made those changes but still am not getting what i need =/

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is very close to working.

The main problem I see is this:

```
var data = {roommate:1};

function redirect(){
    var data=JSON.stringify(data);
```

You've got two variables called `data`, one declared outside the function and one declared inside. While it's fine to have both, the line that does the JSON encoding will only be able to see the local variable, not the one outside. The simplest fix is to rename one of the variables, though you might also like to consider passing in the data as an argument to your `redirect` function rather than relying on grabbing it from outside.

Your server code looks fine apart from the logging. This line isn't going to log anything particularly useful because it's using string concatenation:

```
console.log("post"+ req.body + ' h');
```

`req.body` is an object and concatenating it like this will just give you `post[object Object] h`. Instead try something like this:

```
console.log("post", req.body, ' h');
```

Other that than your server should be fine.

Back in the client code, the logging in your `success` handler is a bit off:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data + 'h'));
```

This is taking a `data` object, concatenating it with `h` to give `[object Object]h` and then trying to JSON encode that string. Instead try something like this:

```
console.log(data, 'h');
```

or, if you prefer, this:

```
// Note the 'h' is outside the stringify
console.log(JSON.stringify(data) + 'h');
```

While the current code does work, you might like to consider using `$.getJSON` instead of `$.ajax` if you're expecting a JSON response.